# Can't open apk file on Android 4.3

Tags: android, eclipse

I build an apk file with Eclipse and I can normally install it on Android 2.3.7, but on 4.3 I cant open apk file and I just get statement "cant open this file".
What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

by default in Android Devices if you try to install an .apk file via OTA installation you will have the message "`cant open this file`".

try this options:

- in you android device:
  `Settings` > `Security` > `Unknown sources`, check to allow installation of apps from sources other than the `Play Store`
- Sometimes you must delete an installed version, it could be signed with a different `Keystore`.

Comment: I have checked this and still I can't install my aps.

Comment: If the app is installed on that device, try uninstalling it and reinstalling it.

Comment: Ok whats the minsdk, targetsdk or max defined into your manifest.xml?